# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\ge1}z^{n^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

What is the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n\ge1}z^{n^4}$$

The exponent $n^4$ is troublesome. Couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For every 0-1 sequence with infinite number of 1's we have
$$
\limsup\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1.
$$

*Remark*: In fact, this gives radius 1 for any nonnegative, bounded sequence with infinite number of positive terms.

Comment: Wow thanks. Didn't think that way at all.

Answer (score 4):

If $|z|<1$, then $|z^{n^4}|=|z|^{n^4} \le |z|^n$, hence the power series converges for $|z|<1$.

The power series diverges for $z=1$. Hence the radius of convergence $=1$.

Comment: (+1) You were 46 seconds faster than me...